# Select Classes (plugins) from a Python list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, class, object

I have a list of classes(plugins) in python, i read them from a folder and store them in a list plugins, like this:

```
#Read all classes from plugin folder    
plugnplay.plugin_dirs = ['./plugins']
plugnplay.load_plugins()
plugins = PluginAlerter.implementors()
```

then all my classes is stored in plugins list

exemple:

```
[<plugins.AddUserAlert.AddUserAlert object at 0x7f593d6d4e90>, <plugins.ElasticSearchDisponibilityAlert.ElasticSearchDisponibilityAlert object at 0x7f593d732210>]
```

I have a daemon to execute every single plugin in my list, and work like a charm

```
for plugin in self.plugins:
  #do the rest of code
```

now with this list i want choose for exemple the second plugin to execute, sometimes i want for exemple execute the first and the third, select differents plugin from my choise

if i chose for exemple the second plugin give this error:

```
#line to select the second plugin
plugins = plugins[1]

File "./Daemon.py", line 78, in __init__ 
    for plugin in self.plugins:
TypeError: 'ElasticSearchDisponibilityAlert' object is not iterable
```

any advice or tip? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You try to iterate over a single item of type "plugins" instead of a list of plugins:

```
# plugins is a list
plugins = plugins[1]
# now plugins is a single element
```

You can force plugins to always be a list:

```
self.plugins = [self.plugins[1]]
```

or more generally:

```
# select one or more plugins from the initial list
self.plugins = selectplugin(self.plugins)
# check type of plugins
if not isinstance(self.plugins, list):
    self.plugins = [self.plugins]
for plugin in self.plugins:
    # do some stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

NEW suggestion

I think you're replacing the `plugins` list with a single plugin (which isn't iterable)

- You say you're running `plugins = plugins[1]` which would replace the iterable plugins with the 2nd plugin, making `for plugin in plugins` fail
- The error suggests `for plugin in plugins` fails because `ElasticSearchDisponibilityAlert` isn't iterable, but that's the type of the 2nd plugin in the original list making this even more likely.

OLD suggestions about indexable and iterable classes:

The `ElasticSearchDisponibilityAlert` class is probably iterable but doesn't implement [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

You can define it and thus support lookup by index, which would be easy if you have an indexable data structure internally (e.g a list):

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
  return self._internal_list_of_plugins[key]
```

Or use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to iterate over the plugins and choose one, which would make each lookup much less efficient, O(n=len(plugins)) instead of O(1).

```
# Grab the 2nd plugin at index 1
i = 1
plugin = itertools.islice(plugins, i, i+1).next()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but every solution you give dont work, the second solution give me the same exact errot, the first solution i put your line codes in my plugin, but i dont know if a do rigtht, but give the same error